# "Present tense after the phrases"

Tags: grammar

Often I come across some sentences that I think are not correct in grammar sense but somehow these sentences were said by the native speaker. For example,

a) I thought this is a naked beach.

b) I thought you two are a team.

c) I thought you don't understand what I say.

d) I and Rachel are going to watch a movie now, and we were just thinking if you want to join us.

Could you tell me why they use present tense after the phrases ‘I thought’ and ‘we were thinking’ instead of past tense? I think they are wrong.

Comment: To be acceptable in that tense, what is thought needs to be in quotation marks: *I thought "This is a naked beach."*, etc.

Comment: Native English speakers don't always use standard grammar. There ain't no reason that you should copy them.

Comment: There is a difference between spoken English and written English, with written English being more structured and logical. With that said, I can't tell you why they used the present tense in the first three sentences. It makes the speaker sound uneducated.

Comment: It’s not an unusual construction. Your own closing paragraph has “could” (past tense of _can_) followed by “use” (present tense) - exactly the construction you’re asking about.